# Conditional formatting based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below table and a formatting function. I would like to include in this function the conditional formatting for a transparent color for both columns `CHECK` **and** `Index` in case that there is `Missing Index` in column `Index`. Is there any way to do it by enhance the below function?

| Percentage1 | Percentage2 | CHECK | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0,09% | 0,15% | OK | Missing Index |
| 0,11% | 0,15% | OK | Index |
| 0,11% | 0,15% |  | Missing Index |
| 0,12% | 0,15% | Check | Index |
| 0,12% | 0,15% | Check | Missing Index |

```
# Color for negative values
def color_negative_red_Check(val):
    if val == "Check":
        color = 'red'
    elif pd.isna(val) == True :
        color = 'transparent' # color transparent for nan
    else:
        color= 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

I am using the below code to apply the function.

```
df.style.applymap(color_negative_red_Check,subset= "CHECK")
```

I want to keep the color for the `CHECK` column as it is now but I would like also to include one more condition to the function to check whether there is `Missing Index` in the `Index` column. Then in this case, I would like to transparent the color for both columns `CHECK` and `Index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use apply not applymap to change both row entries. This is shown in the simplified example below. I am not entirely clear on your logic for changing the colors but the answer shows enough possibilities for you to get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'check': ['check', np.nan ,'check', 'OK'],
                   'idx' : ['yes', 'missing', 'yes', 'missing']
                   })

def style_cell(x):
    color1 = 'color: None'  # set up defaults for no color change
    color2 = 'color: None'
    if x['idx']  == 'missing':
        color1 = 'color: blue'
        color2 = 'color: blue'
    elif x['check'] == 'check':
        color1 = 'color: red'
        Color2 = ' color: red'
    elif pd.isna(x['check']):
        color1 = 'color: blue'
    else:
        Color1 = 'color: green'
        color2 = 'color: green'
    return [color1, color2]

df = df.style.apply(style_cell, axis=1, subset = ['check', 'idx'])

display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: As I explained I need both `CHECK` column **AND** `Index` to have the same color. I edit my question because I forgot the `style`. I want only transparent color for both `CHECK` and `Index` in case there is `Missing Index` and not another color in column `Index`.

Comment: And in cases where there is `nan` value or `Check` value in `CHECK`? In these cases I do not want to change the color in `Index`. This is why I wanted to keep the function that I provided and not change it.

Comment: See edited answer. You can change the colors and logic as required. I am not entirely clear on your color requirements. Is this enough for you to get what you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It worked! Could you please add the first condition to check `if x[idx]  == 'missing': color1 = blue color2 = blue` so I can accept your answer as solution?

Comment: Done. I hope you now have your solution.